# Where objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>() did go?

Tags: entity-framework

I was wondering where objectContext.**CreateObjectSet**() did go in Entity Framework 4 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that hard to find... but here you go: System.Data.Objects namespace in the System.Data.Entity assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383062.aspx